# Faço leitura de 576.73 porém ele é exibido como 576.729980!

Tags: c

**Problema**

O código-fonte é somente para retornar a quantidade de notas e moedas com base em um valor de entrada.
Porém, estou tendo problemas para manipular o valor da variável **aux**. No exemplo demonstrado, o valor de *input* é `576.73`. Mas, como podem ver, a variável **aux** tem perda e isso está fazendo meu programa funcionar erroneamente.

**Código**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   float N;
   float aux;

   scanf("%f", &N);

   aux = N;
   printf("aux = %f\n", aux);

   printf("NOTAS:\n");
   if (aux / 100)
   {
      aux = aux / 100;
      printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 100.00\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 100;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 100.00\n");
   }
   if (aux / 50)
   {
      aux = aux / 50;
      printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 50.00\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 50;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 50.00\n");
   }
   if (aux / 20)
   {
      aux = aux / 20;
      printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 20.00\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 20;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 20.00\n");
   }
   if (aux / 10)
   {
      aux = aux / 10;
      printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 10.00\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 10;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00\n");
   }
   if (aux / 5)
   {
      aux = aux / 5;
      printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 5.00\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 5;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 5.00\n");
   }
   if (aux / 2)
   {
      aux = aux / 2;
      printf("%d nota(s) de R$ 2.00\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 2;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 2.00\n");
   }

   printf("MOEDAS:\n");
   if (aux / 1)
   {
      aux = aux / 1;
      printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 1.00\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 1;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00\n");
   }
   if (aux / 0.5)
   {
      aux = aux / 0.5;
      printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.50\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 0.5;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 0.50\n");
   }
   if (aux / 0.25)
   {
      aux = aux / 0.25;
      printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.25\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 0.25;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 0.25\n");
   }
   if (aux / 0.1)
   {
      aux = aux / 0.1;
      printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.10\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 0.1;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 0.10\n");
   }
   if (aux / 0.05)
   {
      aux = aux / 0.05;
      printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.05\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 0.05;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 0.05\n");
   }
   if (aux / 0.01)
   {
      aux = aux / 0.01;
      printf("%d moeda(s) de R$ 0.01\n", (int)aux);
      aux = aux - (int)aux;
      aux = aux * 0.01;
   }
   else
   {
      printf("0 nota(s) de R$ 0.01\n");
   }
   printf("aux = %f\n", aux);

   return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
aux = 576.729980
NOTAS:
5 nota(s) de R$ 100.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 50.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 20.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 10.00
1 nota(s) de R$ 5.00
0 nota(s) de R$ 2.00
MOEDAS:
1 moeda(s) de R$ 1.00
1 moeda(s) de R$ 0.50
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.25
2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.10
0 moeda(s) de R$ 0.05
2 moeda(s) de R$ 0.01
aux = 0.009965
```

Comment: Usando matemática de pontos flutuantes, a soma não é comutativa nem associativa. As seguintes somas **podem** apresentar resultados diferentes: `(a+b)+c` e `a+(b+c)`

Comment: não faz sentido neste site colocar tags entre colchetes no título pedindo ajuda. Nem tampouco tags de linguagem entre colchetes no título. Você já etiquetou está questão como sendo C, o jeito como você criou o título (e posteriormente reeditou para) não contém nenhuma informação relevante para sanar sua dúvida. O pedido de ajuda por motivos óbvios, a linguagem porque esse problema já está cadastrado como C.

Comment: Leia as perguntas (e suas respectivas respostas) que marcaram como duplicatas desta sua. Existe a explicação para o seu problema nelas. Se restou alguma dúvida após a edificante leitura, daqui a pouco você terá reputação suficiente para perguntar diretamente na resposta alheia o ponto específico de sua dúvida. Se achou que nenhuma das perguntas te responde satisfatoriamente, deixe claro no corpo do texto da sua pergunta que as duplicatas não são suficientes para sanar sua dúvida, explicando mais ao fundo qual o cerne do seu questionamento que ainda não foi devidamente tratado.

Comment: Particularmente eu percebi que sua dúvida já foi respondida em uma dessas questões. Quem marcou esta pergunta como duplicata também percebeu assim. Se quiser uma abordagem menos informal enquanto ainda não tem a reputação necessária para fazer comentários livremente, pode por um comentário aqui me marcando que tentarei te ajudar. Mas antes de tentar entrar em contato comigo, absorva com carinho as perguntas e as respostas relacionadas nas duplicatas